# how can add more images in array list in android

Tags: android

I am starting to game development adding bitmap images in to array list how can implemented

```
for(int i =0;i<9;i++)
{
  resizedBitmap[i] = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, (i%3)*newWidth, (i/3)*newHeight,newWidth, newHeight);            
}
```

Given 9 images are storing array list display random order how can implemented its urgent

Comment: Its a jigsaw puzzle, right? :)

Comment: yes this puzzle game purpose can please send some source code related these link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can achieve what you are attempting to achieve.
One such way is to ditch the array, and use an ArrayList instead.

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> mBitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(9);
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    mBitmaps.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, (i % 3) * newWidth, (i / 3) * newHeight, newWidth, newHeight));
}

Collections.shuffle(mBitmaps);

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = mBitmaps.get(i));

    //Do something
    //...
}
```

Comment: I have 28 images with the names startimg01 to 28 respectively. How do I add those images particularlty?

Comment: If you are meaning that you want to call these images back by name as opposed to index, you can use a Map<String, Bitmap> instead of an array. To add: mBitmaps.put("img01", bitmap); To retrieve: Bitmap bitmap = mBitmaps.get("img01");